# Error while importing a local python library

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I want to import a local python file (lumapi.py) using Jupyter-Nootbook. I have installed Python-2.7.14 on Windows 10.

This error message is displayed when I try to import the source code*.

```
WindowsError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6b82ac779e5e> in <module>()
----> 1 import lumapi

C:\Program Files\Lumerical\FDTD\api\python\lumapi.py in <module>()
     97     return iapi
     98 
---> 99 iapi = initLib()
    100 
    101 class LumApiError(Exception):

C:\Program Files\Lumerical\FDTD\api\python\lumapi.py in initLib()
     54 
     55 def initLib():
---> 56     iapi = CDLL(INTEROPLIB)
     57 
     58     iapi.appOpen.restype = Session

C:\Users\Mohamed Mansour\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.pyc in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    364 
    365         if handle is None:
--> 366             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    367         else:
    368             self._handle = handle

WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I tried to solve the problem myself using Anaconda.

```
>> pip install -f https://github.com/Illumina/interop/releases/latest interop
Requirement already satisfied: interop in c:\users\mohamed mansour\anaconda2\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13 in c:\users\mohamed mansour\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from interop)
>> python -m interop --version
1.1.4
>> python -m interop --test
..............................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 30 tests in 0.300s

OK
```

The problem still persists. Any idea how to resolve this error?

*You can check the full source code from this [link](https://gist.github.com/MohamedElRayany/457c2e4d9d3ec1027376e1d28ad4c476).

Comment: Did you locate the lib `INTEROPLIB` on your system?  Try to CDLL IT by hand.

Comment: I tried to search for the library `INTEROPLIB`, but I could not find it on the whole operating system.

Comment: One might think that it's not installed.  In that case, the error doesn't come as a big surprise.  Python modules often expose the API of other system libraries.  This might be the case here.  You will need to install the library interoplib (what ever that is) onto your system first.

Comment: Thank you @Jus for your comment. I also believe this is the problem. Can you tell me how can I install this library? 
PS: I am a beginner with python.

Comment: I don't know how to install this interoplib.  This subtask has nothing to do with python as far as I can tell.  You'll probably want to ask on a MS-specific forum.